# netlink, link to libnl-3 and libnl-1

Tags: linker, netlink

I have an application that uses libnl. It can use either versions (1 or 3), and during configure it tries first to use ibnl3 and fallback to libnl-1 if libnl3 was not found.

My app uses another library that also uses libnl.
The problem is that I only have libnl1-dev on my machine so my app must use it.
But the library that I use uses libnl3 (was installed with yum i guess it's static linked)
so i have both version and my application crashes!!

here are some prints

```
ldd myapp.so|grep libnl
        libnl.so.1 => /lib64/libnl.so.1 (0x00007fda33eb5000)
        libnl-route-3.so.200 => /lib64/libnl-route-3.so.200 (0x00007fda32a3d000)
        libnl-3.so.200 => /lib64/libnl-3.so.200 (0x00007fda3281b000)

yum list|grep libnl
    libnl.x86_64                            1.1.4-3.el7               
    libnl-devel.x86_64                      1.1.4-3.el7               
    libnl3.x86_64                           3.2.28-2.el7              
    libnl3-cli.x86_64                       3.2.28-2.el7              
    libnl.i686                              1.1.4-3.el7                
    libnl-devel.i686                        1.1.4-3.el7                
    libnl3.i686                             3.2.28-2.el7               
    libnl3-cli.i686                         3.2.28-2.el7
```

if in install libnl3-dev it fixes the issue
is there another solution?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> if I install libnl3-dev it fixes the issue is there another solution?

There are other solutions, but the bottom line is that you can only have `libnl.so.1` *or* `libnl-3.so.200`, but not both.

Fixing this by "going all in on `libnl-3`" is the simplest solution.

The alternative is to "go all on on `libnl-1`", which means rebuilding anything that requires `libnl-3` from source (against `libnl-1`). This is assuming that your other dependencies *can* be built against `libnl-1` at all (which is by no means guaranteed).